# why matlab can not plot a right graph for this function

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot this function in MATLAB, but it can't give the right plot.

[image: function]

When θ = 0, and M = 1.5, we can get there are two roots by hand(0<β<=π/2): 
β1 = arcsin(2/3) = 0.7297, β2 = π/2.
My MATLAB code is this:

```
m = 1.5;
z = 0;
b = 0.1:0.001:pi/2;
f = 2*cot(b)*((m^2*(sin(b).^2)-1)/(m^2*(1.4+cos(2*b))+2))-tan(z);
plot(b,f)
```

The plot is this:

[image: plot1]

You can see all the value of f(β) are less than 0 except β = π/2. That's not what we got by hand.
Then if we use :

```
m = 1.5;
z = 0;
b = 1:0.001:pi/2;
f = 2*cot(b)*((m^2*(sin(b).^2)-1)/(m^2*(1.4+cos(2*b))+2))-tan(z);
plot(b,f)
```

From the plot you can see the value of f(β) are larger than 0(I'm sorry I can only post one image because I don't have 10 reputation...).

Why MATLAB can't plot the right graph, did I make some mistakes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has to do with using matrix operations instead of element-wise operations. Part of your expression:

```
(m^2*(sin(b).^2)-1)/(m^2*(1.4+cos(2*b))+2)
```

evaluates to a single number `-0.0062` instead of a vector. This is because you use `/` instead of `./` and Matlab could not notice the error because you use `2*cot(b)*` instead of `2*cot(b).*`. After addition of two dots in aforementioned places seems to solve the issue:

```
m = 1.5;
z = 0;
b = 0.1:0.001:pi/2;
f = 2*cot(b).*((m^2*(sin(b).^2)-1)./(m^2*(1.4+cos(2*b))+2))-tan(z);
plot(b,f),grid on
```

And the result:

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes senses! And this also explains why the ezplot can give the right plot because the function I use for ezplot doesn't have `.*` .